# Rails - How do I pull in associated model data into a controller json call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have two models that are associated with each other.

```
Customer has_one :primary_contact
```

And I would like to pull this data out in a json object so that the primary_contact model is associated with the Customer object.

Right now my controller does this :

```
@customers = current_account.customers.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @customers.to_json, :layout => false }
end
```

But I woud like to also include in these customer objects, their primary contact info as well.
How would I go about pulling this information in a associated context so that I get this data in jQuery as :

```
value.primary_contact.name
```

Right now, I can pull the json out for the customer object with this :

```
value.name
value.address
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json), use the `:include` option:

> To include associations, use `:include`.
>
> ```
> konata.to_json(:include => :posts)
> # => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
> #     "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true,
> #     "posts": [{"id": 1, "author_id": 1, "title": "Welcome to the weblog"},
> #               {"id": 2, author_id: 1, "title": "So I was thinking"}]}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To include associations, use :include.

```
@customers = current_account.customers.all(:include => :primary_contact)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @customers.to_json, :layout => false }
end
```